# Running variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables

I am quite new with TensorFlow, I am trying to use variables, but I do not get what I expect

When I declare a constant into tensorflow, and then I run into a session it works. but when I try to do the same with a variable, it does not.

Below you see simple experiments from the command line

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2019-05-23 10:13:49.540813: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>>> a = tf.constant(5.)
>>> print(sess.run(a))
5.0

>>> b = tf.Variable(5.)
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\gpapari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.

>>> print(b)
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
>>> print(sess.run(b))
```

After executing the last line, I get a terribly long error.
What is the meaning of the error/warnings I get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a tensor which initializes all variables in your session, e.g.:

```
# Build graph
b = tf.Variable(5.)

# Get init tensor for all variables defined in the graph
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize all variables for the session
sess.run(init_op)

# Use variables in session
print(sess.run(b))
```

Edit to add: perhaps this would be less confusing when you consider that variables are often initialized not using a constant, e.g.:

```
tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([5], 0, 10))
```

so an initializer needs to be executed in the session.

Comment: thank you!! So, if I understand well, the line of code [b = tf.Variable(5.)] does not mean [variable b is initialized with value 5], but [variable b WILL BE initialized with value 5 when the global_variables_initializer will be run inside the session]. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly